# Language integrated query in Kotlin?

Tags: linq, kotlin

I'm working on porting to Kotlin one of my on C# projects which uses certain features of linq. As an example lets take the following linq query:

```
from a in A
from b in B
from c in C
select fun(a,b,c);
```

In C# this allows to chain functions of any type then collect the results in an easy to read way which is preetty much may requirement.
This is equivalent (more or less) to:

```
A.SelectMany(a => B, (a, b) => new {a, b}).SelectMany(t => C, (t, c) => fun( t.a, t.b, c));
```

It is not a problem to achieve functionality of Enumerable.SelectMany in Kotlin but it is still as noisy as the C# equivalent.

Is there any way to achieve something similar in Kotlin without fiddling explicilty with nested tuples but closer to the linq?

Comment: To me this looks more like `A.flatMap { a -> B.flatMap { b -> C.map { c -> fun(a, b, c) } } }` Still nested, but not as verbose as yours. And no tuples.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this is something I considered and will probably use this it in the end.
Another approach I was thinking of was to use a chain infix functor which which returns nested tuples ' t<t<t<a,b>,c>,d> ' then extend this with something like ' t<t<t<a,b>,c>,d>.select<e>( a,b,c,d =>e f) = f(a,b,c,d) ' . I'll probably have to generate lots of code for this purpese to handle nested tuples at various levels

Comment: Those nested tuples look horrible, like one of those abominations from the FP world, where fancy concepts trump any real-world concerns such as performance or memory :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marko Topolnik provided the following as a comment, but it is actually a valid solution:

```
A.flatMap { a -> 
    B.flatMap { b -> 
        C.map { c -> 
            fun(a, b, c) 
        } 
    } 
}
```